# Play audio from any video using php

Tags: php, audio, video

I have a video and I want to play it in audio and video both format.
I did not want to convert it in mp3 and download it.
I want to run it online.
Can i do this. Remember, I have only one file which in video format.
Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use http://ffmpeg.org/

This is a library that allows you to manipulate videos.

Ffmpeg is a shell tool, so if you want to run it from  PHP script you have to follow this guide:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP

Comment: i think `ffmpeg` allow to convert and download not to play online.